# Is there a web-application that provides the ability for interested people on the ground to "stalk" a flight?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, flight-status

I am about to emigrate to Australia. There are a number of people interested in tracking the status of my transit across the pacific.

**Is there an online application that will serve to highlight the route, identify where the plane is on that route, and notify the interested parties if there are delays?**

For example: if [flightwise](http://flightwise.com/tracking/) offered a way to pre-program flight-plans for future dates and distribute that via a URL, that would be the kind of tool I was looking for.

Scenario: Flight on the 19th. ROC - ATL - LAX - SYD flights DL 1584, 17, and 17. I'd like to be able to generate a URL now that would provide tracking.

Answer (score 6):

Try **[FlightAware.com](http://flightaware.com/)**. Like FlightRadar24 and Flightwise, FlightAware provides information about flights in progress such as geographic coordinates, radar track, and current speed an altitude. Unlike the others, however, FlightAware offers a unique URL for each flight, including future flights, that can be bookmarked or distributed in emails or other messages.

See for example http://flightaware.com/live/flight/UAL863 , in the "Activity Log" table below the tracking map.

I believe they only publish the URLs after a flight plan has been filed, however, so you will only be able to distribute it a few days out at best.

Comment: NB, FlightAware mainly covers U.S. flights.  Coverage for international flights can be hit or miss.  I looked up a few LAX-SYD flights, however, and the data was there.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're probably interested in something like [Flightradar24.com](http://www.flightradar24.com/) - you enter the flight in, and you can see exactly where it is, altitude, speed etc.  I've used it on a regular basis for when relatives or friends are flying in to my city.

Comment: Close. To expand, I'm interested in precomputing a *series* of courses such that I can publish one link to show all 3 legs of the flight.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to build or use specifically a web app. Still, the recently updated Kayak app for iOS allows you to track flights, as does the even more recently updated Flight+, which has a rather gorgeous interface.

Comment: could you explain how? Or does it just show arrival times?

Comment: Hm. You open the app and click the 'Flight tracker' icon. Plane locations are displayed when available.

Comment: Oh so it does actually show the location on a map. Cool.  Don't have iOS and was curious.

Comment: When available, yup.

Answer (score 2):

Via the [NYTimes](http://travel.nytimes.com/2012/07/15/travel/how-the-tough-get-going-silicon-valley-travel-tips.html?hpw) I found that [TripIt](http://www.tripit.com/) can serve as an itinerary repository that can be shared. People can then use this repository to check flight status.

With the map tab, my [itinerary](http://www.tripit.com/trip/public/id/88BCC32F0276) should be able to make magic-lines on a map as my trip progresses.